# Probability of getting a red ball `r` times out of `n` trials?

Tags: probability

I have a bag containing Red and Blue balls (these can be any finite number, but for simplicity, let's assume it to be T.)

Now, let’s say you draw a ball from the bag, note its colour, and put it back in the bag. Let’s say you perform this activity `n` times.

What is the probability that you would get a red ball $r$ times out of $n$? In other words, what will be Probability $P(X=r)$?

Comment: This sampling with replacement involves a binomial distribution

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to post in this forum.

Comment: I guess... nCr * P^r * (1-P)^(n-r) should be the answer.

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque That's correct.

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque That's correct, and it's important here that we're sampling with replacement by putting the balls back into the bag so that our trials are independent, assuming the balls are well mixed. (independence is one of the requirements for Bernoulli trials)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sampling with replacement uses the binomial formula. So, if we say $R$ red balls in the bag and $B$ blue balls in the bag with $R+B=T$ with $n$ draws, the probability that red is drawn $r$ times is:

$n\choose{r}$ $ (\frac{R}{T})^{r}(\frac{B}{T})^{n-r}$